# How to skip data when working with files C language

Tags: c, file

I have an issue with as assignment regarding files.

Here is the assignment:

I am asked to write a code for a program that adds to each line in a text file, the number of that line. for example if the original file was:

```
Hi my name is Oria
I study programming
I love dogs
I use stackoverflow
```

It will be changed to:

```
1 Hi my name is Oria
2 I study programming
3 I love dogs
4 I use stackoverflow
```

But I don't know how to skip a line. After I've written the first number, how do I advance the *file pointer to be the first character of the next line?

Comment: Does it make sense to force people to work with text in plain C in order to learn it?

Comment: @maverik: Sure, why not?

Comment: Your current position in the file advances automatically as you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getline(3) to read lines in a loop. Within the loop, you can skip lines at will.

```
while (1) {
    ....
    getline();

    if (...)
        continue;

}
```

Comment: @H2CO3: There's a `getline` function defined by POSIX (but not by ISO C); it avoids the problem `fgets` has with long lines by allocating the line using `malloc` or equivalent. (There are also likely to be other incompatible functions with the same name.) Code using `fgets()` is more portable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the help of writing it into another file.

Read the each line of a input file using fgets and start the loop count, then write to output file with count and data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *src, *dest;
char buf[64];
int i = 0;
src = fopen("in.txt", "r");
dest = fopen("out.txt", "w");
while(fgets(buf, 64, src) != NULL){
    i++;
    fprintf(dest, "%d %s", i,buf);
}
fclose(src);
fclose(dest);
return 0;
}
```